# Partial Class to Programatically Rename Navigation Property in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm working in C#, using Entity Framework 5, .NET 4.5

From what I understand, best practices for Entity are to use partial classes when extending or modifying base functionality so you don't lose your changes when the model is rebuilt.

I have a table with two FKs to another table as follows:

```
ItemTable:
ID
Name

ParentChildTable:
ChildID (FK to ItemTable.ID)
ParentID (FK to ItemTable.ID)
```

When building the EDMX from the database, it properly reads in the FK relationships and creates appropriate object references. Unfortunately, the navigation properties are poorly named, eg. ItemTable and ItemTable1. I would like to rename the navigation properties, and can do so through the designer, but wondered if there is a way to do it in a partial class.

My end goal is simply to have the navigation properties named ChildItem and ParentItem, rather than the automatically generated ItemTable and ItemTable1. I fully understand how to create partial classes, decorate properties, etc. I just need a pointer in the right direction for how to handle this navigation property scenario.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the Answer of @jere but adding a [NotMapped] data annotation, so EF will not try to map these new properties when EF works with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before with recursive relationships, but why change them in code?? I think you're much better off doing it in the designer itself, it makes it much easier to keep track of what you changed too.

That being said, I think you can't "rename" the properties in code. You could do something like this though

```
public partial class ItemTable
{
    public ItemTable ChildItem
    {
       get
       {
          return this.ItemTable;
       }
    }

    public ItemTable ParentItem
    {
       get
       {
          return this.ItemTable1;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason not to do it in the designer is the same reason you would use partial classes for any modifications to the entity model. If I ever have to rebuild the model, my designer changes get chewed up. For instance, if I change the table and need to drop and re-add it to get it updated, I'll lose my custom nav properties.

Comment: Also, though your answer does work, it only accomplishes half of what I'd like. Do you know of any way to get rid of the poorly named navigation properties, or at least hide them from intellisense?

Comment: I think as long as they show up in the designer they'll show up as properties in Intellisense. And from what I've read, the only way is to either change the names directly in the designer or wrap the poorly named properties with appropiate names.

Comment: How about modifying template which generates code from your edmx? Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx

Comment: That seems interesting, but in my personal opinion creating a whole template by hand just to change the name of some navigation properties is a little too much... I'd go with the wrapper approach in this situation, but it's up to you!