# Navigational Properties naming in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I have multiple fields in a table referencing the primary key of one table:

1. Users

   1. CountryId int
   2. CurrencyCountryId int
   3. MobileCarrierCountryId int
2. Country

   1. Id int

When I import this structure in EF, it scaffolds the Navigation Property for CurrencyCountry and MobileCarrierCountry as Country1 and Country2 respectively, although I used a proper naming convention for foreign keys in the database as FK_User_Country_CurrencyCountry and FK_User_Country_MobileCarrierCountry.

I tried to name the Foreign Keys as FK_User_CurrencyCountry and FK_User_MobileCarrierCountry but it still generates Country1 and Country2 only.

One solution was renaming the navigation properties manually in the `edmx` file, but I don't know if that's efficient--after I renamed the navigation properties to what I want  deleted one of the Models and re-generated, to check if the navigation properties of User table reverts back to default, but it doesn't.

Comment: just curious, why kind of work are you doing with FKs that you have to rename them?

Comment: not sure what you meant, i have 3 fields referencing to another table and it's generating weired nav property names that's the problem, i am getting, i don't think, i am doing something new, it's a common approach to have a multiple fields referencing another table.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please read the edit help & advanced help re formatting using 'markdown' annotations.

Comment: You can pretty much override everything and specify manually in `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext`

Comment: Can you help me with a sample example of renaming Navigational Properties from Users1 to CurrencyCountries and Users2 to MobileCarrierCountries through OnModelCreating

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS Please ask a (single specific researched non-duplicate) question in a question post, not in a comment. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: This one might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146410/16606026
EF6 makes me missing EF Core... I am using Rider and it doesn't have .edmx designer, also we're doing DB first so quite frequently we re-generate the models. I am considering about adopting that approach in the linked thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same thing happen. I just renamed the properties in the edmx file and never had a problem.

I wasn't aware that the name of the FK could affect the name of the navigation property. I have on occasion given an FK a "non-standard" name but I've never seen the nav property have any other name than the target table (plus sequence number when needed to make the name unique).

Comment: Similar experience in EF6. I used both SSMS and DataGrip, which generates FK by different naming styles, both results in same result. Kinda hope EF6 can do the namings like Core too...